# Can "tar" backup incrementally?

Tags: tar, incremental-backup, hash, md5

I have my home folder with a few GB.

Is it possible to run tar on it, create a home.tar.gz, and then for changed files, it creates home1.tar.gz only with modified files from previous tar (thus being an incremental backup)?

I would like to check the resulting checksum files and export them as well like home.md5, home1.md5, etc. (I know this could be another process, but interesting as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is very similar to the way [`backup2l`](http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/) operates. You declare a home directory to backup and the 'backup scheme' (basically, the levels of backups).

The end result is a set of tar.gz files with incremental backups. You don't even need the `backup2l` tool to restore files (although is very convenient).

Optionally it can generate md5 checksums (option `-m`).

`backup2l` is a bash script, so you can make it fit your needs.

Comment: I was looking for JUST the tar utility, but since this backup2l is just a bunch of bash scripts, it's still simple. And this way I can learn from it's source, it looks like it's design is very clean. Thanks for this suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, [here is a tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/tar/Incremental-Dumps.html) to do just that.